# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

So I'm just starting to learn classes and i'm trying to do an assignment. I keep getting these 
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89I3G.png)

and I dont know what I'm doing wrong.
I went back to the beginning and ran the program more often and this is the 
[simplest code that gives me the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q58tK.png)

I found a few similar questions but none of them helped me

Answer (score 0):

You have declared, but have not defined, the `stringSet` constructor:

```
stringSet::stringSet() :
    strengur()
{
}
```